# Oracle SQL case when missing right parantheses

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have this `case when` statement as subquery somewhere in a query that I need to fix and I admit I have no idea what it does, but it gives me `missing right parentheses`, can someone help me to fix the syntax?

```
       (SELECT *
          FROM (case when length(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 2 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 3 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 4 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 5 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 6 THEN
        (SELECT

         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 5, 1),
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
         SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 7 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 6, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 5, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 8 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 7, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 6, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 5, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 9 THEN
        (SELECT NULL,
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 8, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 7, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 6, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 5, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      when LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) = 10 THEN
        (SELECT SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 9, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 8, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 7, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 6, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 5, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 4, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 3, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 2, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) - 1, 1),
               SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), LENGTH(nationalNumber.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER), 1))

      ELSE
        (SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
      END) NID1
```

Comment: Please investigate/debug your query sufficiently that you can isolate the problem code snippet and make a [mre] (emphasis on Minimal)

Comment: Did you write all that code without trying it even once during the process? Take much smaller steps, and verify each step before taking the next.

Comment: i didn't write anything, it was a pl/sql function and i need to make it work without pl/sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 problems:

1. You cannot have a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` clause.
2. You cannot have `CASE WHEN ... (SELECT multiple, columns ...)` as a `CASE` expression must return a single value.

You probably do not need the `CASE` expression and can use:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER, -10, 1) AS chr1,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -9, 1) AS chr2,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -8, 1) AS chr3,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -7, 1) AS chr4,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -6, 1) AS chr5,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -5, 1) AS chr6,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -4, 1) AS chr7,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -3, 1) AS chr8,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -2, 1) AS chr9,
       SUBSTR(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,  -1, 1) AS chr10
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LENGTH(NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) BETWEEN 2 AND 10
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER) AS
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ab' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcde' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdef' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefgh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefghi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefghij' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefghijk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcdefghijki' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| CHR1 | CHR2 | CHR3 | CHR4 | CHR5 | CHR6 | CHR7 | CHR8 | CHR9 | CHR10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b | c |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b | c | d |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b | c | d | e |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| *null* | *null* | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| *null* | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i |
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GR-n2lU7)

Comment: does this select every case of the ```case when``` ? i see much less code, those are basically functions inside packages and i need to make it work with no ```pl/sql```, and after i looked at the function and the requirements, they want to select every case inside the ```pl/sql``` function in the mentioned ```case when``` as separate column, does your solution does exactly that?

Comment: @FarisAdnan Even he answers, will you implicitly trust him, or will you test it anyway? (In short, you can answer your own question simply by doing the testing you should always be doing.)

Comment: i cant test anything, that's the problem, there is no data

Comment: @FarisAdnan Of course you can test it, you generate the sample data you want to test against (exactly like I have done).